# Moving reputation from one user to another

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

A few months ago, I started using English Language and Usage Stack Exchange. I signed in as a guest and that worked for me for quite a while, using the same computer and browser the entire time. I didn't bother fully making an account and signing up with email and password and confirming my account and all that. But not long ago, I wanted to ask a question on Writer's Stack Exchange. I must've ignored the "join this community" button (or maybe it wasn't there because I wasn't technically a registered user), and I created a new account on Writer's Stack Exchange. Using the new account, I asked the question found [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/23963/how-many-times-should-i-use-the-word-said-in-one-page), which gained the new account 16 reputation on the site. Take note, that on the [new account](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/19857/akrs20) has the same user name (akrs20) and at the time of creation, the same email (which I later changed to a different email account on the account I am currently using). I am no longer able to access the new account to edit anything, accept the answers or claim the reputation I gained there (which isn't much, I know, but I'm a new user with very little reputation, and 16 is more than my current reputation). A few days ago, I actually finalized the account I have on EL&U with a different, real email (the email I originally used to sign in as guest didn't actually exist; I didn't actually intend to use Stack Exchange or anything other than that initial question, but apparently, that changed) and then used that account to join Writers and ask yet another question with that account ([here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/use-of-separating-fiction-into-parts)).

Now that I have explained my situation, here is my question: Is there any way to get the reputation from my unregistered account ([this one](https://writers.stackexchange.com/users/19857/akrs20)) to my registered account ([this one](http://stackexchange.com/users/8134368/akrs20?tab=accounts))?

---

Edit: While we're on the topic of transferring reputation from one account to another, I have another concern (this one relates to EL&U). Before I joined any Stack Exchange, before I asked my first question and before I created an unregistered account, I actually answered a question as a guest, again with the same user name (akrs20) and the same fake email. I answered [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314776/how-would-you-say-something-like-telling-important-information-to-others-with/314850#314850), [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/314850/167616) and this account (that doesn't really exist and I can't access) has 11 reputation. Is there any way to get the reputation from this answer to my current EL&U account?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 3):

This will need to be handled by an SE employee (moderators don't have account-merge tools).  I suggest you use the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page to explain the problem.  Include links to the profile pages for all involved accounts, and you'll also need to tell them something secret to prove they're yours, like the email addresses you used to create the accounts.  If there's anything else they need they'll reply and tell you what to do.  Best wishes on your upcoming reunification.